# Adobe AIR 1.5 - Package AIR installer as a native Windows Executable (.EXE)

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air, executable

Hello StackOverflow community,

Is there any way to package the installer for an Adobe AIR application using Adobe AIR 1.5 as an executable (.EXE) file?

I found that this is possible for Adobe AIR 2.0, but it requires an upgrade to Adobe AIR 2.0 runtime. Are there any other options using the Adobe AIR 1.5 runtime?

Thanks,
Mauricio